# In zabbix java geatway how can we provide runtime JAVA_HOME property for JDK without affecting existing JAVA_HOME property

Tags: java, linux, monitoring, zabbix

I am using zabbix for monitoring java base application server and want to enable jmx monitoring. in order to jmx monitoring will need to configure java gateway on server and agent
I have added java gateway on zabbix server, but we facing problem when going to enable java gateway on application server.
All application using JRE and zabbix java gateway required javac and jar with is normally come with JDK. 
My question is how can we define separate JAVA_HOME variable property to use JDK in zabbix java gateway, because we dont want to effect on existing JRE property.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to `javac` and `jar`, I presume you talking about building the Java gateway from Zabbix sources.

One way to accomplish what you are asking is to prepend the path to JDK binaries during configuration, like so:

```
$ PATH=/home/user3700399/jdk-1.7.0_45/bin:$PATH ./configure --enable-java
```

Another, since Java is platform-independent, would be to compile Java gateway on a server you have no problem compiling it on, and just copy the files over. If you run `make install`, the necessary files will be in `sbin/zabbix_java` directory in the installation path.